# C# Locate duplicates within a column of an multidim arraylist

Tags: c#, linq

I have a varying DataTable where I have to locate duplicate entries of some combined column values.

I saved the data that need to be searched through within a multidimensional array with two columns both containing strings. Each row of data was added as such a array into a list.

The list looks like this and I have no control of the data that I'm getting:

```
List<string[,]> List = new List<string[,]>();
string[,] TempListArray1 = new string[dt.Rows.Count, 2];
```

An Data Exemple:

```
 ID   | Name
ds-1a | CD34
1s-kj | AB12
```

The amount of rows can be up to a couple thousand.

Now I want to locate multiple entries in the second column of that arraylist. I found the powerful functions of Linq for such an amount of data but it seems quite complex for a beginner like me.

Could someone suggest a way to use Linq since my other option seems to be to iterate through all the data for each entry in the column.

I tried it with this but don't know how to use the groupby filter for multidimensional Arrays:

```
var DuplicateElementsGroup = List.GroupBy(x => x.?????)
                                 .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                                 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this directly from the DataTable and bypass stuffing all the data into arrays.

`dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x["Name"]).Where(y => y.Count() > 1);`

Comment: I would like to do it like that as well but I need to make a string out of multiple colums before comparing/grouping them. Or can I use multiple conditions instead of a single one?

Comment: You can use multiple conditions, this just filters where there is more than one entry with the same value in the Name column. What else do you need to compare on?

Comment: I have 4 colums to be more specific with the titles: Source, Param1, Target, Param 2. Thus I this build a string adding all of them together. Can I use GroupBy multiple times in a single command?

Comment: `.GroupBy(x => (x["Source"], x["Param1"]....));` etc will work for that

Comment: Thank you very much. I had to downgrade my Nuget Version to 4.3.0 for System.ValueTuple to be accepted but it worked like a charm.